# 32 bit vs 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm new to the Ubuntu community and I have a question:
I've noticed while downloading both 32 bit and 64 bit versions that the 32 is referred to as i386 (which I assume is an Intel reference) and the other is referred to as amd64.

Are they written specifically for each architecture? I have both a 64 bit Intel desktop and a 64bit AMD laptop. I installed the 32 bit on the laptop by accident, having made the install "pen" a while back for a 32 bit laptop and it worked fine. Then I installed the 64 bit version on top of that, again no problem.

But I rely more on my desktop (more powerful, for one thing) and it's running the aforementioned Intel, an i5 quadcore sandybridge 3.3Ghz to be exact.

So again, does it matter? Were the 32 and 64 written for different architectures?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

64 bit architecture was initially developed by AMD, which was then picked up by Intel. Hence, traditionally, 64 bit architecture is also referred to as amd64. It's merely a naming convention, you can install the amd64 iso on Intel's 64 bit-capable CPU as well.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the explanation, Serg. While UFT-8 answered the question simply, you answered what was going to be my next question, "Then why the naming convention?" Thank you, that was a bit of history I was unaware of and Ubuntu was probably making a homage to.

Comment: @SeanMohrhoff I was curious about this very same question before, so I knew how to answer. Historical context sometimes is pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer supports 64 bit (which it probably does if it's not older than 10 years), install the 64 bit version. Don't get distracted by "amd" or "i386".